# Is there a central location where I can keep input files?

Tags: input

I made a macros file which I use in every paper I write. For years, I've included a copy of this file in every LaTeX folder, but this is inconvenient because when I add a macro, the change appears only in one folder and I'd like it to appear everywhere. I use a Mac with TeXShop, and going to Open ~/Library/TeXShop in the TeXShop menu brings up a folder including an "Input files" subfolder. Clearly that is where my macros file should go, but then how do I load it into my current paper? (I don't know how to create a "path" on a Mac.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can put your macros is a file such as `myzzz.sty` then just reference it as `\usepackage{myzzz}` I woul dexpect that it is in ~Library but not under texshop but rather under texmf, in vanilla texlive  you would put in a folder under `~/texmf/tex/` but I don't know the Mac defaults

Comment: Thanks, David. Do I put my macros file in a folder named (say) myzzz.sty, and where would I store it?

Comment: as I say I think on the mac the default TEXMFHOME is `~/Library/texmf/` but I don't have a mac so can't be sure, the default in linux/windows is `~/texmf/`   some mactex user will be along soon and confirm the default mac paths, (or `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` will probably show you

Comment: You can use UNIX style pathnames with `\input{../../library/macros.tex}` (for example).

Answer (score 1):

With a current texlive 2019 you could put your files in some personal texmf tree. I e.g. have local files in `.../UFlocaltexmf/tex/latex/ufmacros`. I then added this texmf with

```
tlmgr conf auxtrees add .../UFlocaltexmf
```

to my search path (with the `...` correctly filled in). This should work with every OS.

Comment: Thank you all. I know nothing about Linux or Unix or personal texmf trees, so much of your advice is above my head. I opened ~Library/TeXShop under the TeXShop menu and added a folder named "Input", where I inserted my macros file (say, "GKmacros"). If this is OK so far, then all I need now is the proper command in my local TeX file replacing "\input GKmacros" which will tell my Mac where to find it. I tried "~Library/TeXShop/Input/GKmacros.tex" and "\input~Library/TeXShop/Input/GKmacros.tex" but neither worked.